# PHP Upload Progress Session

Tags: php, progress-bar

I am trying to create an upload progress bar with PHP.
I saw the new feature of PHP 5.4: [upload progress session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php).

This is my HTML code:

```
<form id="upload" action="ajax/progress.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>" value="dupload" />
    <input id="file1" type="file" name="file1" />
    <input class="btn primary" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

And this is progress.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix") . 'dupload';

if (!empty($_SESSION[$key])){
    $current = $_SESSION[$key]["bytes_processed"];
    $total = $_SESSION[$key]["content_length"];
    echo $current < $total ? ceil($current / $total * 100) : 100;
}
else {
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    var_dump($_FILES);
}
```

AJAX:

```
$('#upload').submit(function () {
    interval_id = setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/progress.php6",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }, 200);
    return false;
});
```

All the ini settings are right. (session is enabled, name and prefix is right)

I am always getting an empty session array. What's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your reading not writing to the session... how woukd it ever not be empty

Comment: What do you mean? There's nothing in the doc saying I should manually write to the session, it should write it automatically.

Comment: If your file really named `"progress.php6"`?

Comment: Yup, php6 extension is required in my server if I want to use PHP 5.4..

Comment: Are you running PHP via FastCGI?  http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php#109091

Comment: Don't think so, how can I know for sure?

Comment: I've got same issue... I have it working perfectly fine outside of Kohana. PHP does the writing to session but for some reason with Kohana you can't access it or see it (that's if it's created at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wasn't able to sort it out so I used XMLHTTPREQUEST "progress" action and that worked well.
Thanks!

Comment: I think, that this one SHOULD not be accepted ;). Maybe it is a solution, but ABSOLUTELY it isn't an answer...

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in one POST request, you can do AJAX requests, and read session while file is uploading.  After file is uploaded, the `session.upload_progress.name` key is removed so you are getting an empty array.

Comment: Well I also tried settings an AJAX request every second after a form submit, empty array as well.

Comment: What server u use ? if nginx there are some problems with this new feature of php, and i have to use iframe+apache to handle progress bars : )

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your form is not getting submitted, as you have return false in

```
$('#upload').submit(function () {
    interval_id = setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/progress.php6",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }, 200);
    return false;
});
```

and it initializes interval, so the page always return null as nothing is being uploaded. Try using http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form, it submits form