# Including several PHP versions in Apache, switchable via AddHandler directive

Tags: apache, mod-php

A shared web host I'm using is offering several versions of PHP on the same server: 5.2, 5.3 and 5.4. They make it possible to switch between these versions by naming the file extensions `.php54` and `.php53` respectively, or via an .htaccess directive:

```
AddHandler php5.4-script .php
```

I have not been able to completely figure out how their Apache server is configured to support this though. Everything I found seemed to say that only one mod_php can be compiled into Apache at a time. Would this suggest that `php5.4-script` is some sort of custom wrapper module? Or are there obscure ways in which different PHP modules can be compiled under different handler names?

Comment: Is this what you need? http://linuxplayer.org/2011/05/intall-multiple-version-of-php-on-one-server

Comment: So basically it's a (Fast)CGI wrapper?

Comment: Great. Go ahead and post an answer...? :)

Comment: Your hosting is **not** using `mod_php`. Please check [Find out how PHP is running on server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414054/find-out-how-php-is-running-on-server-cgi-or-fastcgi-or-mod-php) to learn how to verify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the resource I've found](http://linuxplayer.org/2011/05/intall-multiple-version-of-php-on-one-server) after researching on this topic, it is as you already thought `a (Fast) CGI wrapper` which allows you to change the PHP version used via e.g. .htaccess .

How to achieve this is explained thoroughly here: http://linuxplayer.org/2011/05/intall-multiple-version-of-php-on-one-server .

In case the site is not reachable, here I'm going to list the steps:

1. Install required dev packages
2. Compile and install
3. Create a fastcgi wrapper script

   - Build and install e.g. php-5.3 with fpm enabled
   - Configure php-fpm
   - Start fpm
   - Install and setup mod_fastcgi, mod_fcgid
4. Update the Apache config file
5. Restart Apache