# Using "auto_prepend_file" into ".user.ini" file in PHP

Tags: php, ini

I want to load the file `variables.php` (that simply contains variables) at the run of any pages of my project so I can use the variables from any place.

I created a file called `.user.ini` (and placed it in the root folder):

```
; Automatically add files before PHP document.
; http://php.net/auto-prepend-file
auto_prepend_file = /Volumes/www/project_name/admin/libs/variables.php
```

It doesn't work. It seems that PHP doesn't read the .user.ini file.

php.ini is right configured by default:

```
user_ini.cache_ttl    300           300
user_ini.filename     .user.ini     .user.ini
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: can you put the exact location of this file i.e. d:/.user.ini and see if it works

Comment: Does your PHP interpreter run as CGI, FastCGI or a similar SAPI?

Comment: From the documentation: “The file is included as if it was called with the require function, so include_path is used.” Would you mind to put it inside the folder, accessible by the web server and give a relative path which is included (e.g. admin/libs/variables.php)?

Comment: @Satya: The above path is the exact location on my file system (mac osx)

Comment: @mudasobwa: Tried to use relative path but doesn't work yet

Comment: [Find out how PHP is running on server (CGI OR fastCGI OR mod_php)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414054/find-out-how-php-is-running-on-server-cgi-or-fastcgi-or-mod-php)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: thanks. It's "Apache 2.0 Handler" (`apache2handler`) on my local pc, but on the hosting I will have to work is `cgi-fcgi`. I need to get it work on both cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, [the manual says it all](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php):

> Since PHP 5.3.0, PHP includes support for configuration INI files on a
> per-directory basis. **These files are processed only by the CGI/FastCGI
> SAPI**. This functionality obsoletes the PECL htscanner extension.

And:

> If you are using Apache, use .htaccess files for the same effect.

... though it actually refers to the Apache **module** (`mod_php`).

If you need SAPI-independent custom settings I'm afraid you'll have to use *both*. You can minimise the maintenance burden if you keep those settings to the minimum (most PHP directives can be provided in PHP code itself). And you need to ensure that `.htaccess` settings don't crash when `mod_php` is not available:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value auto_prepend_file /Volumes/www/project_name/admin/libs/variables.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Good, on apache2handler it works (using htaccess) but on cgi I get this issue: the browser keep loading for a while, then it shows the page with a bunch of error about any php functions used in the page but I know it has loaded the variables.php file because a test echo.

Comment: Well, if code is not right it doesn't matter how you load it :-?

Answer (score 1):

I think `.user.ini` should be located in *project* root folder, for example, `/Volumes/www/project_name/.user.ini`

> In addition to the main php.ini file, PHP scans for `INI` files in each
>   directory, starting with the directory of the requested PHP file, and
>   working its way up to the current document root (as set in
>   `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`). In case the PHP file is outside the
>   document root, only its directory is scanned.

[.user.ini documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php)

Comment: From your link: «Since PHP 5.3.0, PHP includes support for configuration INI files on a **per-directory basis**».

Comment: Tried to place .user.ini in root folder but it doesn't work yet