# Is it possible to place all custom functions files in a single folder and make all php scripts access them by default?

Tags: php

For example, if "Functions" folder contains "Function_1.php", "Function_2.php" and "Function_3.php" files, how to make all php scripts access the 3 functions by default?

Comment: yes it is possible, you could probably create an autoload php file that handles all inclusion of said files and use that with the pages that needs it.

Comment: @Kevin, thanks for your suggestion, but that's not a "Default Access" since "autoload.php" needs to be included in every single script!

Comment: you could try loading it via htaccess, if it's a class you could also use `spl_autoload_register`. alternatively, you could use composer too to autoload your files

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24780209