# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function apache_getenv()

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, laravel-4, fatal-error

> Host: Amazon Web Services
>
> Domain: Godaddy
>
> SSL: Godaddy
>
> Framework: Laravel 4.2
>
> PHP: PHP5.6
>
> Apache: Apache 2.4.16
>
> File located: /var/www/html/test

My code:

```
$api_request = 'https://'.apache_getenv("HTTP_HOST") . apache_getenv("REQUEST_URI");
```

Error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function apache_getenv()

It looks like it doesn't exist.

Laravel App Located at: html. Then another two folders with laravel: test and live.

- html/ (Laravel app landing page)

  - app/
  - bootstrap/
  - packages/
  - public/
  - vendor/
  - test/ (Laravel app)
  - live/ (Laravel app)
  - index.php

It works properly at html app. but in test app the function doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Is your [Server API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414054/find-out-how-php-is-running-on-server-cgi-or-fastcgi-or-mod-php) the Apache handler?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález `Server API` `Apache 2.0 Handler`

Comment: What's wrong with using `$_SERVER`?

Comment: maybe interesting? [getenv — Gets the value of an environment variable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php).

Comment: @JonStirling I tried. Gives me the error of undefined index `HTTP_HOST`

Comment: I think we need a clarification... Are we talking about a web application (that runs trough Apache) or some command line test suite?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález check my answer with follow up question. this could help a lot of people hehe

Comment: @JonStirling check my answer with follow up question. this could help a lot of people hehe

Comment: @RyanVincent check my answer with follow up question. this could help a lot of people hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `apache_getenv` is disabled in your php.ini

Enable it by

Edit php.ini (By default `/etc/php.ini`)

Remove `apache_getenv` from `disable_functions` section

save and exit.

restart apache/php handler.

Comment: what word should I search in php.ini?

Comment: i found it but its empty `disable_functions =`

Comment: There was nothing to erase.

Comment: Are you using a shared hosting environment? If yes then there might be override in server's main php.ini.

Comment: check my answer with follow up question. this could help a lot of people hehe

Comment: The error message is "PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function apache_getenv()", not "Warning: apache_getenv() has been disabled for security reasons".

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] and  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

In place of `apache_getenv` some times apache does not allow you to access the functions without the module activation.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried. Gives me the error of undefined index `HTTP_HOST`

Comment: check my answer with follow up question. this could help a lot of people hehe

Comment: @MarlonBuendia - Seriously, all symptoms suggest you are running PHP from the command line, not through a web server.