# Memory limit not increasing in php.ini on godaddy Plesk

Tags: php, plesk, memory-limit

I have been trying to increase memory limit of **php.ini** file on godaddy Plesk server for 2 days but it is not increasing.

I created php_info file to check the path of my `php.ini` file. On Plesk hosting of godaddy, my **php.ini** file is located at following path which is not accessible by me:
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP54\php.ini**

After reading many answers on the stackoverflow, I have created a file named as php.ini, wrote **memory_limit = 256M** in it and placed it on the root of my hosting. But still memory limit is not increasing in the php_info [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brQge.png).

Need help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, that's not how it works, PHP doesn't load all the `php.ini` files it finds. Is it running as CGI or as Apache module?

Comment: Reference: [Runtime Configuration](http://php.net/manual/bg/configuration.php)

Comment: Since I have windows Plesk, I must be using FastCGI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP only loads the `php.ini` file it's configured to. It will not load all files with such name it finds in the request path.

Once you [find out whether PHP is running as CGI OR Apache module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414054/find-out-how-php-is-running-on-server-cgi-or-fastcgi-or-mod-php#16414507) you need to set the directive in the file and syntax that [documentation](http://php.net/manual/bg/configuration.php) explains:

- `.user.ini` for CGI
- `.htaccess` for Apache

Alternatively, you can do it in your [own PHP code](http://php.net/ini_set):

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint **ini_set('memory_limit', '256M')**. It is working perfect. But I want to add **extension=php_printer.dll** to my php.ini. How can I add this line using ini_set('');

Comment: That's an entirely new question but, in short, you can't. PHP is not designed that way—extensions are system-wide.

Comment: Ok, I got it. But is there any solution you are known to? Any hint?