# How to get apache's version?

Tags: php, apache

When I try to run `apache_get_version()` function on my website, I get an error:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function apache_get_version() in /srv/www/mywebsite.com/index.php:44 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /srv/www/mywebsite.com/index.php on line 44

However this works in my localhost.
I tried

```
function apache_version()
{
    $ver = explode(" ",$_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"],3);
    return ($ver[0] . " " . $ver[1]);
}
echo apache_version();
```

This should echo the server version on apache though it doesn't echo the version

Comment: That function is only available if PHP is compiled and installed as a normal Apache module. If it's not, well, this happens.

Comment: Andrew I've read that on a website but how to get the version?

Comment: You'll have to compile it yourself mate. See [here](http://dcx.sap.com/1200/en/dbprogramming/pg-php-compiling-apache.html)

Comment: Andrew I can't do that cause i don't have access to the terminal

Comment: There's no way around it. Use the function you posted in your answer.

Comment: which php version u r using?

Comment: Naincy Gupta 7.1.1 Just found that php_info() doesn't work too

Comment: Did you mean `phpinfo()` without the underscore?

Comment: Matt Gibson It's disabled in my host for security reasons

Comment: Ask your host provider for apache's version.

Comment: Charlotte Dunois Email sent. Is there a faster way though? they usually take 1-2 weeks to response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']` To get the the web server you're running. As Andrew said you can compile it yourself from [here](http://dcx.sap.com/1200/en/dbprogramming/pg-php-compiling-apache.html). There's no way around it

Comment: This comes from the response headers. If the server does not report its version, you'll just get `Apache` or even nothing at all.

Answer (score 2):

From [the introduction to Apache functions](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.apache.php):

> These functions are only available when running PHP as an Apache module.

If you run PHP as CGI/FastCGI or any other SAPI, there's just no reliable way to determine Apache version because the interaction of PHP with Apache is minimum. If the server does not report it (thus you can read it somewhere at `$_SERVER`) you're out of luck.

You can also [determine how PHP runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414054/find-out-how-php-is-running-on-server-cgi-or-fastcgi-or-mod-php) with `phpinfo()`.

Comment: I can see that the Server's API is CGI/FastCGI

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('httpd -version');
```

Comment: Nope it doesn't echo anything at all

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Michael I'm using windows but the host is using Linux I believe

Comment: So you have no access to terminal use?

Comment: Michael Nope but i can still run shell_exec

Comment: Can you do a echo shell_exec('php -v');

Comment: For debian you need to use echo shell_exec(' apachectl -V');

Comment: Michael tried that before it echo's information about PHP

Comment: What does phpinfo say under system

Comment: PHP 7.1.1 (cli) (built: Jan 19 2017 17:37:38) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

Answer (score 0):

To determine if you can read the Apache version, create a phpinfo.php file as mentioned by Álvaro González.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Run the file and if the PHP Variable **$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']** is listed with a value, use the following in your PHP code:

```
$apache_version = $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'];
echo "$apache_version";
```

The reported value is dependent on the configuration and may not be listed at all. Otherwise you might get something like Apache/2.4.29 (Unix) or Apache/2.2.22 (Win64) etc.

Answer (score -4):

```
echo apache_get_version();
```

It will print the Apache's complete version detail.

Comment: OP's reported issue was an error running this very function. "Call to undefined function apache_get_version()"

Comment: Well, still its live function http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-get-version.php