# Can't change display_errors value

Tags: php

I can't turn off `display errors` for my website. I use **ISP Manager** control panel. It is *Off* in all php.ini files and settings. But still warnings and notices are showing. Even using `ini_set()` right in the script doesn't work. Can you help me with this?

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 0);
phpinfo(); // display_errors is still On On

ini_get('display_errors'); // returns 'stderr'
```

Comment: error_reporting(0) tried?

Comment: Is [ini_set()](http://php.net/ini_set) actually failing? "Returns the old value on success, `FALSE` on failure".

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález It returns `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, something like:

```
var_dump(ini_set('display_errors', 0));
```

… produces:

```
bool(false)
```

I can think of two ways to intentionally prevent `display_errors` from being  changed:

1. [Disabling](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) `ini_set()` altogether in system-wide INI file, which produces different symptoms:

   ```
   Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons
   NULL
   ```

   This can be checked anyway:

   ```
   var_dump(ini_get('disable_functions'));
   ```
2. Hard-coding `display_errors` in Apache settings using [`php_admin_flag`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php#configuration.changes.apache), which only applies if PHP runs as Apache module but effectively produces a boolean false.

I believe we're in #2. You may want to check [whether PHP runs as Apache module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414054/find-out-how-php-is-running-on-server-cgi-or-fastcgi-or-mod-php); I'm not aware though of any way to verify by yourself if `php_admin_flag` is being used. If that's the case, I reckon you're out of luck:

> `php_admin_flag` name on|off
>
> Used to set a boolean configuration directive. This can not be used in
>   `.htaccess` files. Any directive type set with `php_admin_flag` **can
>   not be overridden** by `.htaccess` or `ini_set()`.

If you're in control of Apache settings this is something you can easily fix. Otherwise, I suggest you ask hosting support about this. IMHO, it isn't reasonable to enable `display_errors` in a production server, let alone *force* it:

> ; This directive controls whether or not and where PHP will output errors,
>   ; notices and warnings too. **Error output** is very useful during development, but
>   ; it **could be very dangerous in production environments**. Depending on the code
>   ; which is triggering the error, sensitive information could potentially leak
>   ; out of your application such as database usernames and passwords or worse.
>   ; For production environments, we recommend logging errors rather than
>   ; sending them to STDOUT.
>   ; Possible Values:
>   ;   Off = Do not display any errors
>   ;   stderr = Display errors to STDERR (affects only CGI/CLI binaries!)
>   ;   On or stdout = Display errors to STDOUT
>   ; Default Value: On
>   ; Development Value: On
>   ; Production Value: Off
>   ; http://php.net/display-errors

Comment: Seems like PHP runs as FPM/FastCGI (Server API = FPM/FastCGI).

Comment: @Graduate Hmmm... I'm not very familiar with FastCGI with but [FPM seems to support php_admin_value too](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php).

Answer (score 1):

**Overview**

There are a few different types of error reporting function in PHP. Luckily we have a decent explanation of these in the [PHP docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors).

I typically use the three in the examples below. Let's walk through those.

**Breakdown Docs**

This function sets the error reporting level.

`error_reporting()`

> The error_reporting() function sets the error_reporting directive at
>   runtime. PHP has many levels of errors, using this function sets that
>   level for the duration (runtime) of your script. If the optional level
>   is not set, error_reporting() will just return the current error
>   reporting level.

This first function takes a parameter of an integer or a named constant. The named constant is recommended in case future version of PHP release new error levels. That way you will always know what to expect after upgrading to a newer version of PHP.

This next mode decides if errors will be printed to the screen or not.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1)
```

> This determines whether errors should be printed to the screen as part
>   of the output or if they should be hidden from the user.

The last one handles errors that happen during PHP's startup sequence. When you turn `display_errors` on it does not handle errors that occur in the startup sequence. This is partially the reason why a lot of times people do not understand why they are not seeing errors even though they have turned error reporting on.

> Even when display_errors is on, errors that occur during PHP's startup
>   sequence are not displayed. It's strongly recommended to keep
>   display_startup_errors off, except for debugging.

This will tell the app to log errors to the server.

```
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
```

> Tells whether script error messages should be logged to the server's
>   error log or error_log. This option is thus server-specific.

**Example**

To turn off error reporting in a file try this,

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
error_reporting(0);
```

To turn on error reporting in a file try this,

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

**Answer**

If you want to log errors but do not want them to show up on the screen then you would need to do this,

`ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Or try,

`ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: I need `error_reporting` to log errors. I just don't want them to show on my web pages.

Comment: I have covered this in my answer. Let me know if that does not work but it should. There is a whole list of error logging in the docs you can try if not but I am pretty sure that will work.

Comment: It seems like `ini_set('display_errors', 0)` is not honored by my PHP engine.

Answer (score 0):

In our case it was issued by the PHP FPM configuration. Some values were pinned with `php_admin_flag` or `php_admin_value`, so it was **not** possible to set them at runtime with ini_set().

From the php-fpm documentation:

It's possible to pass additional environment variables and update PHP settings of a certain pool. To do this, you need to add the following options to the pool configuration file.

**Example #1 Passing environment variables and PHP settings to a pool**

```
php_admin_value[sendmail_path] = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f www@my.domain.com
php_flag[display_errors] = off
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 32M
```

PHP settings passed with `php_value` or `php_flag` will overwrite their previous value. Please note that defining disable_functions or disable_classes will not overwrite previously defined php.ini values, but will append the new value instead.

**Settings defined with `php_admin_value` and `php_admin_flag` cannot be overridden with ini_set().**

See also [PHP-FPM-Configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35362207)