# PHP 7.4 on Ubuntu Server ignore .user.ini

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, apache2.4

I am running Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS VM.
This VM is running to run and manage LAMP stack + SFTP access to manage website files.
Apache2 seems to work properly, but PHP 7.4 does not apply ".user.ini" settings.

We created ".user.ini" file inside "/var/www/html" path (default Apache2 path in Ubuntu).
Permission are setted properly, but Apache2 does not load settings inside this file.

All files and folder are owned by webdev:www-data (webdev is a custom user that permit us to access to Linux VM using SFTP). Chmod is 775 for this file in this moment.
I am not running any custom virtual host, so I am using *000-default.conf* settings in

```
/etc/apache2/site-enabled/000-default.conf
```

Apache2 continue to apply PHP.ini settings.

Can someone help me?
Thanks a lot!
Federico

Comment: `PHP includes support for configuration INI files on a per-directory basis. These files are processed only by the CGI/FastCGI SAPI. This functionality obsoletes the PECL htscanner extension. If you are running PHP as Apache module, use .htaccess files for the same effect.` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

Comment: How can i check if I am running PHP as module or not?
Should I specify something in my 000-default.conf file? I did not found any info about it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414054/find-out-how-php-is-running-on-server-cgi-or-fastcgi-or-mod-php has some information on that

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue in this way:

If you need to use ".user.ini" settings you must use CGI/FastCGI
You can see if you are using Server API (for PHP) via CGI/FastCGI or Apache2 Module using "phpinfo()"
In my case Server API was Apache2 Handler (it is not fine for .user.ini)

I disabled PHP as Apache2 module. You can do it `a2dismod phpX.X` (in my case php7.4)
Later I installed php-fpm `apt install php7.4-fpm` and I checked if it is running `service php7.4-fpm status`.

Finally I created ".user.ini" file and I rebooted Apache2 server.

Now all it is working properly

Thanks a lot @aynber :)