# Upload progress bar using session in PHP 5.4 with codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, session

With reference to this tutorial. [Tracking upload progress with php](http://www.sitepoint.com/tracking-upload-progress-with-php-and-javascript/) . I want to make it work in Codeigniter. I am not getting point to start to make it work in CI. I want to upload files and also track progress.

### In my CI view

```
 <?php $arr = array("id"=>"myform");
       echo form_open_multipart("welcome/uploads",$arr); ?>
      <input type="hidden" value="myForm" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>">
      <table>
      <tr>
          <td>file</td>
         <td><input type="file" name="images[]" multiple></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>name</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="naam"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
<div id="bar_blank">
```

### script

```
function toggleBarVisibility() {
  var e = document.getElementById("bar_blank");
  e.style.display = (e.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
}

function createRequestObject() {
   var http;
   if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
       http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   else {
      http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
     return http;
}

 function sendRequest() {
   var http = createRequestObject();
   http.open("GET", "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/welcome/progress' ?>");
   http.onreadystatechange = function () { handleResponse(http); };
   http.send(null);
 }

function handleResponse(http) {
   var response;
   if (http.readyState == 4) {
    response = http.responseText;
    document.getElementById("bar_color").style.width = response + "%";
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = response + "%";

    if (response < 100) {
        setTimeout("sendRequest()", 1000);
    }
    else {
        toggleBarVisibility();
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Done.";
      }
   }
}

 function startUpload() {
     toggleBarVisibility();
    setTimeout("sendRequest()", 1000);
 }

 (function () {
      document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = startUpload;  //error is here
})();
```

According to above tutorials, its in core php. When submitting form CI request to controller `dashboard/addRoom` and my page gets refresh anyhow. But in tutorials, Form redirects to `PHP_SELF` (same php file). I am not getting any idea on it. Please help me.

### Controller

```
 function progress()
    {
        session_start();

        $key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix") . "myForm";
        if (!empty($_SESSION[$key])) {
            $current = $_SESSION[$key]["bytes_processed"];
            $total = $_SESSION[$key]["content_length"];
            echo $current < $total ? ceil($current / $total * 100) : 100;
        }
        else {
            echo 100;
        }
    }
    public function uploads()
    {
        if(!empty($_FILES['images']['name'][0]))
       {
        //uploadinf file code
       }
    }
```

Comment: I have done the file upload and more with this plugin in codeigniter, http://malsup.com/jquery/form/progress2.html

Comment: I don't want to use plugins.

Comment: where you stuck? have you tried something?

Comment: Problem for me is that. When I submit the form in Codeigniter. Then it goes to controller and page is refreshed. Then Can it be possible to run ajax.

Comment: what is the name of controller and mehtod that display this form?

Comment: can you provide in your question what you've done so far to us, so we can help you :)

Comment: I had edit my question now. I had tried it But cannot make it success. Can you please let me know whats wrong.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do it with only jQuery then i have used [jQuery Form Submit](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) Plugin, which will give you the progress and more. As you said in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727436/upload-progress-bar-using-session-in-php-5-4-with-codeigniter/29861702#comment-47848761) you don't need any plugin then follow these steps and implement like the tutorial suggesting.

Lets assume you have controller dashboard and method `addRoom` is displaying the your html form:

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {


    function addRoom() {

        // Detect URI: http://example.com/dashboard/addRoom/upload_file
        $upload_req = $this->uri->segment("3");

        if( $upload_req == "upload_file" ) {
            // Do the file upload Actions
        }

        // Generate Form
        $this->load->view("Generate_view");
    }

}
```

View:

```
<?php 
    $ar = array("class"=>"form-horizontal");
    echo form_open_multipart('dashboard/addRoom/upload_file',$ar);
 ?>
 <input type="text" name="fileName">
 <input type="file" name="upload">
 <input type="submit" value="add">
 <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

In this case your form is still on the same controller and method even you submit or not.

**Update:** According to updated answer, please use codeigniter default libraries for [Session](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/sessions.html) and [File Uploads](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/file_uploading.html), In case of JS error, use console tab(Chrome) to debug error, or if you are using firefox then use firebug extension to debug Javascript.

Comment: Now set the hidden field as discribed in the sitepoint tutorials and create another model like `progress.php` that will fetch the information through ajax.

Comment: Hi jogesh, I had edited my question with what I had tried. I am getting error in script `(function () {
    document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = startUpload;
})();`

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to show upload progress there are many plugins available to do so, I don't know why you specifically mentioned Session in you title.

[Here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) is a very nice and simple plugin which will work with any PHP framework with ease.

**Code Sample**

```
<script>
/*jslint unparam: true */
/*global window, $ */
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io' ?
                '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'server/php/';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I am not allowed to use plugins. :(

Answer (score 2):

You're missing (I don't see it in your code) that the tutorial in your question declare and use an *hidden iframe* in the `target` attribute of the the upload form, this is a way to handle uploads preventing the *form* page to *refresh* (the *action* url will be loaded into the *iframe*).

google for *hidden iframe upload* (and eventually for *formdata upload* which nowadays should be a better way to handle uploads and show progress with few javascript)

here an old example which use the hidden iframe [Ajax File Upload Response Handling](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/response_data.php)

**update**

You should change the code in your view to `$arr = array("id"=>"myForm")`

Currently I see it is `array("id"=>"myform")` (all lowercase)

`getElementById` is case sensitive and you use `.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit`

When you use some javascript and something isn't working as expected the browser's *javascript console* is the first place to look, you should see an error like (chrome):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onsubmit' of null
```

This is because `getElementById` fail to find an element with `id` `myForm` and return *null*, in the html/DOM it is really named `myform`.

**update**

So, I got the thing working, instead of `welcome` controller I've created a new `Upload` controller (uppercase because I'm using *CI 3 dev*, should be easy to adapt it to old versions), below the working files.

The url will be `http://your-host/optional-dir/index.php/upload`.

`application/controllers/Upload.php`:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Upload extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->view('upload');
    }
    function progress() {
        session_start();
        $key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix") . "myForm";
        if (!empty($_SESSION[$key])) {
            $current = $_SESSION[$key]["bytes_processed"];
            $total = $_SESSION[$key]["content_length"];
            echo $current < $total ? ceil($current / $total * 100) : 100;
        }  else {
            echo 100;
        }
    }
    public function uploads() {
        if(!empty($_FILES['images']['name'][0]))  {
            //uploadinf file code
        }
    }
}
```

`application/views/upload.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>upload</title>
        <style>
            #bar_blank {
                border: solid 1px #000;
                height: 20px;
                width: 300px;
            }

            #bar_color {
                background-color: #006666;
                height: 20px;
                width: 0px;
            }

            #bar_blank, #hidden_iframe {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php $arr = array("id"=>"myForm", "target"=>"hidden_iframe");
        echo form_open_multipart("upload/uploads",$arr); ?>
        <input type="hidden" value="myForm" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>file</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="images[]" multiple></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="naam"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        <iframe id="hidden_iframe" name="hidden_iframe" src="about:blank"></iframe>
        <div id="status"></div>
        <div id="bar_blank">
            <div id="bar_color"></div>
        </div>
        <?php include_once(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'upload.js.php'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

`./application/views/upload.js.php`:

```
<script>
function toggleBarVisibility() {
    console.log('toggleBarVisibility');
    var e = document.getElementById("bar_blank");
    e.style.display = (e.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
}

function createRequestObject() {
    console.log('createRequestObject');
    var http;
    if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return http;
}

function sendRequest() {
    console.log('sendRequest');
    var http = createRequestObject();
    http.open("GET", "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/upload/progress' ?>");
    http.onreadystatechange = function () { handleResponse(http); };
    http.send(null);
}

function handleResponse(http) {
    console.log('handleResponse');
    var response;
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
        response = http.responseText;
        document.getElementById("bar_color").style.width = response + "%";
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = response + "%";

        if (response < 100) {
            setTimeout("sendRequest()", 1000);
        } else {
            toggleBarVisibility();
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Done.";
        }
    }
}

function startUpload() {
    console.log('startUpload');
    toggleBarVisibility();
    setTimeout("sendRequest()", 1000);
}

(function () {
    console.log('init');
    document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = startUpload;  //error is here
})();

</script>
```

**notice**

I'm using a raw `include_once` for convenience, because php `base_url` is used inside the javascript, probably would be better have a small inline javascript in the view's html which declare a javascript variable with the `base_url` value then include the static javascript from an assets directory as usual.

Comment: Same thing struck me. I would say right answer!! +1

Answer (score 1):

the tutorial i have seen actually you have to write AJAX in your view, and call the controller via ajax not via form submission with button. so than your page will not get refreshed. take a close look on the tutorial you have provided the link, and when you scroll down you will see javascript where it send HTTP requests via AJAX for example

```
 function createRequestObject() {
  var http;
  if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
     http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   else {
    http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
   return http;
}
```

this is a 1 function where it create XMLHttpRequests to get response from file where you have to get response via XMLHttpRequest from your controller.

Regards